# How can convert a string array to int array

Tags: php, arrays, string, int

I have a string array like this,

```
C:\wamp64\www\date\task.php:37:
array (size=6)
  0 => string '_06_CM_1640=[04];' (length=17)
  1 => string '_06_CM_1899=[05];' (length=17)
  2 => string '_06_CM_2094=[24];' (length=17)
  3 => string '_06_CM_2096=[12];' (length=17)
  4 => string '_06_CM_1871=[16,12];' (length=20)
  5 => string '_06_CM_3369=[09];' (length=17)
```

and I want to convert it to int array.

```
$_06_CM_1640 = [4];
$_06_CM_1899 = [5];
$_06_CM_2096 = [12]; 
$_06_CM_2094 = [24]; 
$_06_CM_1871 = [16,12]; 
$_06_CM_3369 = [16];
```

How can I do this in PHP? please assist me about this matter?
regards,
Bos

Comment: You mean make individual variables? I am not sure I understand what you are trying to do....

Comment: Using [`array_map`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) seems like a good start to me.

Comment: And a [regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9665101/regex-to-find-string-within-s) to split/extract from the square brackets.

Comment: @Jeremy Harris, yes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `array_walk`

```
array_walk($aa, function($v, $k) use (&$new){
  $inner = explode('=', $v);
  $new[$inner[0]] = $inner[1];
});
print_r($new);// this will give you array with keys
```

Now you can use `extract($new)` to make each key as variable and access them using `$_06_CM_1640`

Example :- https://3v4l.org/ddKZj

Comment: Dear Rakesh Jakhar your code is good. But I want to separately arrays, like this below.$_06_CM_1640 = [4];
$_06_CM_1899 = [5];
$_06_CM_2096 = [12]; 
$_06_CM_2094 = [24]; 
$_06_CM_1871 = [16,12]; 
$_06_CM_3369 = [16];

Answer (score 0):

This splits it down in stages, first by `=` which gives the name and value, then using `trim()` to remove any of `=[];` round the values, finally explode the string to make it into an array of numbers...

```
$arr = [0 => '_06_CM_1640=[04];',
    1 => '_06_CM_1899=[05];',
    2 => '_06_CM_2094=[24];',
    3 =>  '_06_CM_2096=[12];',
    4 =>  '_06_CM_1871=[16,12];',
    5 =>  '_06_CM_3369=[09];'];

$output = [];
foreach ( $arr as $entry )  {
    list($name, $values) = explode("=", $entry,2);
    $output[$name] = explode(",", trim($values, "=[];" ));
} 


print_r($output);
```

gives..

```
Array
(
    [_06_CM_1640] => Array
        (
            [0] => 04
        )

    [_06_CM_1899] => Array
        (
            [0] => 05
        )

    [_06_CM_2094] => Array
        (
            [0] => 24
        )

    [_06_CM_2096] => Array
        (
            [0] => 12
        )

    [_06_CM_1871] => Array
        (
            [0] => 16
            [1] => 12
        )

    [_06_CM_3369] => Array
        (
            [0] => 09
        )

)
```

I would actually leave it as an array rather than individual values.

Answer (score 0):

It's not very secure but something like this do the trick :

```
<?php
function convertStringArrayToIntArray($src)
{
    $int = [];
    foreach ($src as $key => $value){
        $split = explode('=', $value);
        $newKey = $split[0];
        $newValue = $split[1];
        $newValue = str_replace(['[', ']', ';'], '', $newValue);
        $newValue = explode(',', $newValue);
        array_walk($newValue, function(&$value, &$key){
            $value = intval($value);
        });
        $int[$newKey] = $newValue;
    }
    return $int;
}

$src = [
    0 => '_06_CM_1640=[04];',
    1 => '_06_CM_1899=[05];',
    2 => '_06_CM_2094=[24];',
    3 => '_06_CM_2096=[12];',
    4 => '_06_CM_1871=[16,12];',
    5 => '_06_CM_3369=[09];'
];
$ints = convertStringArrayToIntArray($src);
extract($ints);
var_dump(get_defined_vars());
//        $_06_CM_1640 = [4];
//        $_06_CM_1899 = [5];
//        $_06_CM_2096 = [12];
//        $_06_CM_2094 = [24];
//        $_06_CM_1871 = [16,12];
//        $_06_CM_3369 = [16];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$arr = [
    '_06_CM_1640=[04];',
    '_06_CM_1899=[05];',
    '_06_CM_2094=[24];',
    '_06_CM_2096=[12];',
    '_06_CM_1871=[16,12];',
    '_06_CM_3369=[09];'
];

$results = [];

foreach($arr as $v) {
    if (!preg_match_all('~ (?: , | (?<key> \w+ ) = \[ ) (?<val> \d+ ) ~xA', $v, $m))
        continue;

    $results[$m['key'][0]] = array_map('intval', $m['val']); 

}

var_dump($results);

// extract($results); // if you want to create the variables
```

Comment: dear Casimir et Hippolte, your code is very usefull but I want to individual array

Comment: @Bos: that's why I wrote the last commented line if you want to do that. `extract` create individual variables named with the array keys. Uncomment it and do for example `print_r($_06_CM_1640);`. Note that I commented it since using `extract` is generally a bad practice.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a new one array:

```
foreach($arr as $stri){
    $tmp = explode('=',$stri); 
    $ar[$tmp[0]] = explode(',',preg_replace('~[\[\]\;]~', '', $tmp[1]));  // clear values
}
```

and then use [extract()](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/php-extract-function/) function:

```
extract($ar);

print_r($_06_CM_1871);
print_r($_06_CM_3369);
```

Outputs:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 16
    [1] => 12
)
Array
(
    [0] => 09
)
```

**[Demo](https://3v4l.org/i45Il)**